# "lang" field disappears in JQuery post

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I had a really odd bug today, which only appeared in the production version of some software I am working on. I'm still scratching my head trying to understand what happened.

I'm using `jQuery.post()` to send form data to a PHP script on the server. One of the fields in the data was called "lang". On my development machine everything went fine, but on the production version, the value in that field would just disappear.  I eventually debugged it as far as the call to `jQuery` post. In the debugger I could see that lang had a value at that point, but looking at the network trace it shows the `lang` field as an empty string.

The main difference between my development and production version is that for development I use a local non-minified copy of **jQuery**, but in production I grab it from **ajax.googleapis.com** (currently using jQuery 1.11.3).

After much pulling out of hair, I finally just changed the name of the field to "lng" instead, and everything started working correctly.

Is this a known problem? Are their certain POST variables one needs to avoid when using **jQuery**?

Partly I'm also just posting this here to save some other poor souls from having the same issue.

Comment: Maybe some framework are just highjacking your POST processing it and than passing further? (like params white-listing / cleaning)?

Comment: @Justinas Worth considering, but I'm only using jQuery and jQueryUI.

Comment: Than check how you get, process and send that data. No code - no help